# Azure Connection Problems

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am new to Azure. I am switching a EC2 VM from Amazon to Azure. It is a silverlight project using Ria Services. The same code on azure has many more dropped queries (DomainServiceError). Is there something special I have to do with azure to keep the connections from dropping?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Handling Transient Connections in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh689724.aspx)?

> The bottom line is that your application must be able to handle possible connection termination at any time, and recover from it. Connection termination may happen from network error conditions, but also from the normal operation of the data center. Applications must plan for this, and expect to encounter it.

Also, check [this](http://windowsazurecat.com/2010/12/sql-azure-and-entity-framework-connection-fault-handling/) out if you are using Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will research it. I didnt realize my mail settings were set to not send me mail when there are new messages.